# UserDefaults keypath publisher doesn't fire beyond first value

Tags: swift, swiftui

Given a obj-c keypath

```swift
@objc dynamic var someProp: String { string(forKey: "someProp") }
```

A regular publisher:

```swift
private let sub = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.someProp).sink { print($0) }
```

This publishes only works for the first value (e.g. the current value).

However observing the `sub` publisher from SwiftUI works fine:

```swift
.onReceive(pub) { value in
    print("received", value)
}
```

This publishes any subsequent updates.

Any ideas why the former doesn't work?

Edit: Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```swift
public extension UserDefaults {
    @objc dynamic var value1: Int {
        integer(forKey: "string1")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

    private let pub = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.value1)

    var body: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            var value = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "value1") as? Int ?? 0
            value += 1
            debugPrint("SET", value)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "value1")
        }
        .onReceive(pub) { value in
            debugPrint("UI", value)
        }
    }

    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        private let sub = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.value1).sink {
            debugPrint("SUB", $0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is more context needed to solve this. Try to add a [mre].

Comment: Just curious, why you don't prefer to use `AppStorage`

Comment: "A regular publisher" -- no, once you put the `sink` on the end, it's not a publisher any more. If you're going to do that, you need to store the `cancellable` somewhere -- otherwise it'll go out of scope immediately

Comment: @jnpdx sorry, I thought the `private` makes it clear that this is a property.

Comment: @burnsi of course, sorry. Let me add a minimap reproducible!

Comment: @user1046037 as I understood it, you can't observe changes from an `@AppStorage` property? I'm trying to observe changes to the persisted userDefault value.

Comment: @burnsi I added an MRE 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is how you access and assign your values in the Button action. You are setting the values for the key `value1`. But the publisher observes the key `string1` with the dynamic var named `value1`.

TLDR: You confused the dynamic var with your key

I would recommend you ommit the access via `.value(forKey: "")` and use only your dynamic var.

```
public extension UserDefaults {
    @objc dynamic var value1: Int {
        // add getter and setter
        get{
            integer(forKey: "string1")
        }
        set{
            set(newValue, forKey: "string1")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

    private let pub = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.value1)

    var body: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            //here
            UserDefaults.standard.value1 += 1
            debugPrint("SET", UserDefaults.standard.value1)
        }
        .onReceive(pub) { value in
            debugPrint("UI", value)
        }
    }

    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        private let sub = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.value1).sink {
            debugPrint("SUB", $0)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Prints:

```
"SUB" 0
"UI" 0
"SET" 1
"SUB" 1
"UI" 1
"SET" 2
"SUB" 2
"UI" 2
"SET" 3
"SUB" 3
"UI" 3
```

Comment: Wow. You are right. Thank you so much. I must have been really tired. However, I have one more question. Why won't this setup work if I use `UserDefaults.standard.set(UserDefaults.standard.value1 + 1, forKey: "string1")` instead of `UserDefaults.standard.value1 += 1` . Is the observation only viable for the keypath, not for the key?

Comment: The publisher only is only emitting values if you use `value1`. Thats what the dynamic property is for. If you are using publishers don´t use the `.value(forKey: "")` api.

Comment: I came up with a related question, maybe you have some idea about this, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74455232/swift-userdefaults-publisher-for-non-standard-suite-not-working-correctly