# Swift UserDefaults publisher for non-standard suite not working correctly

Tags: swiftui, combine, userdefaults

Please see the MRE below.
Changing UserDefault suite to a custom one doesn't update the subscription beyond the first value.

```swift
public extension UserDefaults {
    @objc dynamic var value1: Int {
        get { integer(forKey: "value1") }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: "value1") }
    }

    static var other: UserDefaults {
        UserDefaults(suiteName: "other-defaults")!
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private let sub = UserDefaults.other.publisher(for: \.value1).sink { print("SUB", $0) }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            UserDefaults.other.value1 += 1
            debugPrint("SET", UserDefaults.other.value1)
        }
        .onReceive(UserDefaults.other.publisher(for: \.value1)) {
            debugPrint("UI", $0)
        }
    }
}
```

Only the SwiftUI `onReceive` subscription is working.

```
SUB 0
"UI" 0
"SET" 1
"UI" 1
"SET" 2
"UI" 2
```

It works (though with multiple calls) if I set the `standard` UserDefaults suite.

```swift
struct ContentView2: View {
    private let sub = UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.value1).sink { print("SUB", $0) }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            UserDefaults.standard.value1 += 1
            debugPrint("SET", UserDefaults.standard.value1)
        }
        .onReceive(UserDefaults.standard.publisher(for: \.value1)) {
            debugPrint("UI", $0)
        }
    }
}
```

```
SUB 0
"UI" 0
SUB 1
SUB 1
"SET" 1
"UI" 1
"UI" 1
SUB 2
SUB 2
"SET" 2
"UI" 2
"UI" 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution to this, but the explanation is a bit wonky.

My initial suspicion was correct. With your implementation of `other` in the extension you are creating an new `UserDefaults` store every time you are accessing the var. It seems you need to hold on to this store or it will go out of scope and you won´t receive any values. The `UserDefaults.standard` is a shared instance, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416603-standard).

Here comes the strange part: I could only speculate why the `.onReceive` wrapper works as this is implementation detail of SwiftUI. Also why using the `.standard` store is emitting twice (btw. using a single `.other` instance shows the same result) is beyond me.

This implementation should show the desired output:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let otherSuite: UserDefaults
    private let sub: AnyCancellable

    init() {
        print("init")
        otherSuite = UserDefaults.other
        sub = otherSuite.publisher(for: \.value1).sink { print("SUB", $0) }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            // don´t use ohterSuite here or your sink will run twice
            UserDefaults.other.value1 += 1
            debugPrint("SET", otherSuite.value1)
        }
        // the same here
        .onReceive(UserDefaults.other.publisher(for: \.value1)) {
            debugPrint("UI", $0)
        }
    }
}
```

Print:

```
init
SUB 0
"UI" 0
SUB 1
"SET" 1
"UI" 1
SUB 2
"SET" 2
"UI" 2
```

Comment: omg, you're right. Using a shared instance for `other` as well solved my initial problem.

Comment: As for the other two, yes quite the mystery. I think the double posting was mentioned in another question here that I found along the way, but also inconclusive... if I find it again, I'll link it